# React does not call onchange callback of checkbox in jest test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm working on some code that uses a checkbox function (I've stripped off a lot of functionality)

```js
export class MyLovelyCheckBox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    if (this.props.isRequired) this.props.updateType('default');
  }
  handleChecked(checkbox) {
    if (checkbox.checked) {
      this.props.updateType(checkbox.value);
    } else {
      this.props.updateType('');
    }
  }
  render() {
    return <div>
      <Checkbox
        disabled = {
          this.props.isRequired
        }
        checkboxType = 'default'
        handleChecked = {
          this.handleChecked.bind(this)
        }
        value = {
          this.props.type
        }
    />
  </div>;
  }
}
```

The `Checkbox` function is (again stripped back):

```
export default function Checkbox(props) {
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    props.handleChecked(event.target);
  };
  const { checkboxType } = props;

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        disabled={props.disabled}
        id="thisCheckBox"
        value={checkboxType}
        checked={checkboxType === props.value}
        type="checkbox"
        onChange={handleChange}
        aria-checked={checkboxType === props.value} />
      <label
        id="thisCheckBox-label"
        htmlFor="thisCheckBox"
      >
        <Icon icon={checkboxType === props.value ? 'checkbox' : 'checkbox-outline'} size={20} viewBox={'0 0 20 20'}></Icon>
        <span>{props.checkboxLabel}</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The problem comes from my tests, as I'm trying to make sure that the `handleChecked` code is covered by tests. To that end, I've written this test:

```
 it('when clicked, updateTypes is called', () => {
    const updateType = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(true);
    const mountedComponent = create({ updateType }, false, false);
    const checkBox = mountedComponent.find('Checkbox');
    checkBox.simulate('change', { target: { checked: true } });
    expect(updateType).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(true);
  });
```

Where the utility method `create` is:

```
const create = (params, required = {}, shallowlyRender = true) => {
    const props = {
      type: 'generic',

      updateType: () => true,
    };
    const allProps = { ...props, ...params };
    return shallowlyRender
      ? shallow(<MyLovelyCheckBox {...allProps} />)
      : mount(
        <Provider store={store}>
          <MyLovelyCheckBox {...allProps}/>
        </Provider>,
      );
  };
```

Despite my best efforts, I cannot get the `handleChecked` function to be called by the test.

Instead jest outputs:

```
    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(...expected)

    Expected: true
    Received: ""

    Number of calls: 0
```

Where have I gone wrong on this test?

Comment: It seems that in your test you are passing an "updateType" props for the change event handler, but your component expects a "handleChecked" props instead, right ? I cannot see where you specify the handleChecked props in your test setup. But maybe I'm missing something here.

Comment: @Florian updateType is called from handle checked, and handle checked is passed in

Comment: oh right, I missed something :)

Comment: @Florian do you have any ideas?

Comment: unfortunately no, I'm more used to the react-testing-library way. I could elaborate on how I would do that with RTL but this would not answer your question...Maybe you could try to test a visual effect of your callback firing (test like a real user) as a workaround ? This is the RTL philisophy BTW :).

Comment: @Florian I would do, but I think I'd still have the same issue of the function not being called => no visual effect

Comment: If your code works fine (ie the callback is called when you run your app),  testing a visual effect of the callback allows you to forget about the internal implementation, the callback being called etc...You could just write in pseudo code : myButton.click(); expect(visual effect happened); So even if your internal implementation changes the test is still working.

Comment: @Florian I'm trying to improve the coverage though (I recognise that I haven't mentioned that yet.) Also, as the code isn't covered I'm not convinced it is working correctly